# Photoshop CC 2019 Zoom In/Out While Using Lasso Tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools, zoom, cc-2019

I used CC 2021 and in that version has got scroll zoom while using lasso tool. But in CC 2019 I have to do (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space bar</kbd> + Left mouse click.) How can I zoom with scroll while using lasso tool?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my low level English grammar.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. As far as I know, all CC versions support Shift + centre mouse wheel rotate for zooming, regardless of which tool you have selected. Try that.

Comment: Thank you Billy. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Edit > Preferences > Tools and make sure the box is ticked for "Zoom with Scroll Wheel" -

[image]